How to send duplicated query params in get http request using Oauth 1.0
I make the following query in my Insomnia request to the API endpoint:
search?constraintsField=check_entrega&constraintsInitialValue=ok&constraintsField=check_entrega&constraintsInitialValue=parcial

This request requires OAuth 1.0.
My issue is: I make the identical request in my code, but the server returns an 'invalid signature' error. This only happens when there are duplicate parameters in the query, as shown in the query above where I access "check_entrega" twice.
Here's the code I use to make the request:
public ResponseGeneralModel getHttp(URI uri) {
    ResponseGeneralModel responseMessage = null;
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uri);
    httpget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    try {
        System.out.println("Request URI: " + httpget.getURI());
        System.out.println("Request Headers: ");
        for (Header header : httpget.getAllHeaders()) {
            System.out.println(header.getName() + ": " + header.getValue());
        }
        String query = uri.getRawQuery();
        System.out.println("Raw Query: " + query);
        OAuthClientInstance.getInstance().getConsumer().sign(httpget);
        System.out.println(httpget.getURI());
        System.out.println(httpget.getFirstHeader("Authorization").getValue());
        HttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        responseMessage = new ResponseGeneralModel(result, false, response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR - K31" + e.getMessage());
    } catch (OAuthMessageSignerException | OAuthExpectationFailedException | OAuthCommunicationException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return responseMessage;
}

The request in Insomnia works normally, the URI created by my code is correct and identical to the one in Insomnia. However, I get an error when there are duplicate parameters. How do I make the signature in the header account for these duplicate parameters?
